# Expanding sizes between given values

Tags: php, array

This a very simple function to expand the sizes between the given values.

For instance, if the input variable is "S-XL" then the function returns "S, M, L, XL".

Basically I'm not happy with this function.  I think it's too complex for its purpose.

```
function sizexpander($sizes) {
    $sizearray=Array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
    $size1=array_search(strstrb($sizes, "-"), $sizearray);
    $size2=array_search(substr(strstr($sizes, "-"),1), $sizearray);
    while ($size1 <= $size2) {
        $prodsizes.= $sizearray[$size1].", ";
        $size1++;
    }
    return substr($prodsizes, 0, -2);
}

function strstrb($h,$n){
    return array_shift(explode($n,$h,2));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `array_slice` to take the subarray which contains the sizes from `$size1` to `size2`. And then use `implode` to turn this subarray into a comma-separated string. This will simplify your algorithm.

You can also just use `explode` instead of `substr` and `strstr` to split the range string into its parts.

In addition I would recommend changing the variable names of `$size1` and `$size2`. To me the name `$size1` suggests that the variable contains the actual size while in fact it contains its index. Something like `index_of_size1` or `index_from` might be more appropriate.

If I were to write this function, it'd look something like this:

```
function sizexpander($size_range) {
    $sizearray=Array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
    list($size_from, $size_to) = explode("-", $size_range);
    $index_from = array_search($size_from, $sizearray);
    $index_to = array_search($size_to, $sizearray);
    $subsizes = array_slice($sizearray, $index_from, $index_to-$index_from+1);
    return implode(", ", $subsizes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My implementation would be pretty much the same as yours, but removing the `foreach` loop.  It's not required as `array_slice` can do the job with less code.

```
function sizexpander($sizes)
{
     //These should be in order!
     $range = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");

     //Split them into 2 segments, min / max + convert to upper
     $keys = explode("-",strtoupper($sizes));

     //Get the initial index of min
     $min = array_search($keys[0],$range);
     $max = array_search($keys[1],$range);

     //Slice the array and implode.
     return implode(",",array_slice($range,$min,($max - $min) + 1));
}
```

The main problem you had was that you had created a second function using string searching to find your segments.  This has been replaced by `explode` which, as long as there is only ever 1 delimiter, then this would suffice.

Also, the `while` statement has been revoked, along with the string concatenation and been replaced with implode, which takes the found segments of the `sizearray` and implode them by a delimiter.

Comment: `array_slice` takes a starting index and a length, not a starting index and an end index.

Comment: Yea my bad, sorry about the confusion in your question aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Option A:

```
function sizexpander($sizes) {
    $sizeArray = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
    list($minSize, $maxSize) = split('-', $sizes);

    $minIndex = array_search($minSize, $sizeArray);
    $maxIndex = array_search($maxSize, $sizeArray);
    return join(', ', array_slice($sizeArray, $minIndex, ++$maxIndex - $minIndex));
}
```

You can do this with array_filter but it's not as efficient.

If you're uncomfortable with array operations or find the code unclear (i.e. not self documenting) you can do this with a simple enough loop.

```
function sizexpander2($sizes) {
    $sizeArray = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
    list($minSize, $maxSize) = split('-', $sizes);
    $tmp = array();

    foreach($sizeArray as $size) {
        if($size == $minSize) {
             $tmp[] = $size;
        } else if(count($tmp)) {
             $tmp[] = $size;
             if($size == $maxSize) break;
        }
    }

    return join(', ', $tmp);
}
```